# My .txt file association is missing its icon

Tags: windows-xp, file-association

On Windows XP, my .txt file association has no icon. It is quite annoying, and has been going on for several months now.

I've tried to un-associate it using the folder-->options--file types, I've tried to change the association, delete the icon cache, and even tried using ftype and assoc. nada.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've lost your file icon, you can put in another one or find the old one.

First, open up Windows Explorer, then:

> Tools > Folder Options

Scroll down to the relevant file extension, in this case, `TXT`. Select and click **Advanced**.

The **Edit File Type** dialog will pop up.

[image: icon settings]

Click on **Change Icon...**

If you want to find the system default for it, try this location first (edit as necessary for your Windows directory):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
```

If you would rather another icon, maybe one you've dowloaded, just navigate to it by clicking on **Browse...** and opening up the folder.

Click **OK** to save the changes.

The filetype will now show with the changed/reverted icon just selected.

Comment: It's a nice and detailed guide for newbie to set the icon in windows.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, but may fix others'